# Is this set measurable? (Set of points where a sequence converges)

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $M$ be a manifold. Suppose that $u_n:M \to \mathbb{R}$ are measurable and we have $u_n(s) \to u$ a.e. in $M$.

Does it follow that the set $A=\{s \in M : u_n(s) \to u(s)\}$ and $A^c$ are measurable?

I don't know if there is enough data for this problem to be solved.

In my case $M=(0,T)\times S$ where $S$ is a hypersurface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true if and only if the underlying measure on $M$ is *complete*, i.e. if any subset of a null set is measurable. Indeed, the phrasing $u_n(s)\to u(s)$ *almost everywhere* means exactly that the set $A^c$ is contained in a null set. (Note that $A$ is measurable if and only if $A^c$ is. )

If the measure is not complete, meaning that there exist a null set $N$ containing a nonmeasurable subset $M$, then the sequence of functions 
$$u_n(s)=\begin{cases} 0, & s \in M^c \\
(-1)^n, & s \in M
\end{cases}$$
is an example of a function for which the set $A$ of convergence is nonmeasurable.

Comment: Hey thanks. So we don't even need the $u_n$ to be measure.